# How to open "Google::Apis::DriveV2::File" In Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

I'm using the Google Drive api to get a file back and this is what I'm getting for a response: `Google::Apis::DriveV2::File`. I see a bunch of methods on it but I'm wondering how I can open or read this file? I've already tried `File.open` and `File.read` but they both say:

`no implicit conversion of Google::Apis::DriveV2::File into String`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but I found these [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/DriveV2/File). Hope it helps!

Comment: have you checked this gem? https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

Comment: you could probably use this gem: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client. Here you can check the documentation of how to get started: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/apis/drive/v2